# Pass checkbox value to controller from GSP in Grails

Tags: grails, checkbox, gsp

I've a checkbox in my Grails application:

```
<g:checkBox name="reservationAvailable" value="${cafeeInfo.isReservationAvailable}"/>
```

It must be uncheked if isReservationAvailable boolean-value is false and checked if it's true.
When I click on unchecked checkbox, it become checked, then I send a form, but in logs of controller I get false checkbox value. When I update view page, checkbox become empty again.
Using parsing such as:

```
oldCafeeInfo.isReservationAvailable = Boolean.parseBoolean(params['reservationAvailable'])
```

doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: There's no need to use `Boolean,parseBoolean`. You can use `params.boolean`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed, checkbox return "on" string, when it's checked. So available to compare checkbox parameter in response with "on"-constant.

Comment: @KyleLuke, no, unfortunately, it was too long ago